# Airflow Failure

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I try to restore our airflow env by using dokcer-compose up command. But it didn't work. bellow error coming. I did different method to restore this but didn't any of that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd57c.png)

How restore airflow env

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.